# Could not load file or assembly 'Visualization, Version=1.2.0.32003, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net application in which I am using some charts. When I debug the project, I get the following error. I cannot figure out how to get past this error.  I have

1. Given the user "everyone" access to the entire directory that this dll is contained in
2. Deleted the dll and rebuilt the project
3. Deleted the Temporary ASP.NET files in the Windows Directory
4. Restarted IIS
5. Tried to change to a different user in IIS security.
6. Even copied that dll from other machines

[image]

Currently I am removing the Temporary ASP.Net files from my local machine but after some time this error again pops up.

Comment: When you say `dll` are you talking about the `Visualization` dll?  Have you added it as a reference in your project?

Comment: check to make sure that you have that Dll Reference / Assembly added to the `using` in your page header.. also make sure that you manually add the reference to the project from it's perspective location

Comment: Yes. I am talking about the Visualization dll and it is added as a reference in my project.